# Azure- one drive transfer

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, onedrive

I am very new to microsoft azure. I would like to transfer 5gb of files(datasets) from my Microsoft one drive account to azure storage(blob storage I guess), and then share those files to about 10 other azure accounts on azure(I have some idea as to how to share files these files). I am not really sure how to go about it, and I prefer not downloading the 5gb of files from one drive and then uploading to azure. Help would be  greatly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. This question doesn't really fit here, as it's fairly broad and opinion-seeking (many ways to copy files to Azure storage, both with pre-built apps and with APIs/SDKs). As far as downloading? You'll need to download your OneDrive files *somewhere* (as OneDrive isn't an Azure service), so that means either your local computer, hosted VM, Azure VM... There are then OneDrive APIs to consider. Lots of choices. Not single right answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a very genuine question as downloading huge files and uploading them back is a very expensive and time consuming task. You can refer to a template [here](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/49933434732d4846a1fc0aaae72f8998/copy-new-files-to-azureblob-from-a-onedrive-for-business-folder/) which would allow you to do a server side copy.

Hopefully, if not you, someone else would be benefited with this.

Answer (score 1):

David's comment is correct, but I still want to provide a couple links to get you started. Like he mentioned, if you can break this into several questions that are more specific you can probably get much better StackOverflow response. I think the first part of the question could be phrased as 'How can I quickly transfer 5GB of files to Azure storage?'. This is still opinion based to some degree but has a couple more finite answers:

1. [AzCopy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/)/DmLib are, respectively, a command line tool and an Azure library that specialize in bulk transfer. There's a couple options including async copy and sync copy. These libraries are specialized to a greater degree for upload/download from the file system but will get you started.
2. There's a variety of language storage libraries where you can write custom code to connect up with OneDrive. Here is a getting started with [.Net](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/).